# How to detect TreeNode expansion in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm using MVVM to bind a hierarchical tree structure to TreeView in WPF. I'm using XAML code, which looks like follows:

```
<TreeView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        BorderThickness="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Mode=OneWay}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyStatistics}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >                    
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate> 
...
```

I want to be able to intercept node expansion event, and let the node of my tree, that is bound to the TreeView node that is being expanded, do some checks, may be ask user if he's sure (if the operation will take a lot of memory) and cancel the expansion.

How do I do that?

Comment: Are you wondering how to do this *at all,* or how to do it in pure MVVM with no code-behind? (Doing the latter, if you decide it's worth the trouble, would require already having a way to do the former.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not built-in and to achieve this you will have to create a new control derived from `TreeView` and then extend `TreeViewItem`.

There is fair bit involved to achieve this so I hope you can follow along; I won't explain everything so ask questions or do some reading on MSDN on anything you don't understand.

**Creating the TreeView**

```
public class TreeViewEx : TreeView
{

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item) 
    {
        return (item is TreeViewItemEx);
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride() 
    {
        return new TreeViewItemEx(this);
    }

    internal bool PreviewExpandTreeViewItem(TreeViewItemEx item)
    {
        // return true to allow expansion, false to cancel
        return true;
    }

}

public class TreeViewItemEx : TreeViewItem
{
    private readonly TreeViewEx Owner;

    static TreeViewItemEx()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TreeViewItemEx), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TreeViewItemEx)));
    }

    public TreeViewItemEx(TreeViewEx owner)
    {
        Owner = owner;
    }

    private void OnPreviewExpansionMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // we do not care if it already expanded
        if (IsExpanded)
            return;

        e.Cancel = !Owner.PreviewExpandTreeViewItem(this);
    }

}
```

Now, you want to create the default style for your new `TreeViewItemEx`. You can find the [base template on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788727%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

To do this, you will need  copy the base template from MSDN, change the `TargetType` to be `{x:Type controls:TreeViewItemEx}` and then add a `PreviewMouseDown` event to the `ToggleButton` named `Expander` and use the event handler in the item class e.g. `PreviewMouseDown="OnPreviewExpansionMouseDown"`

**Note:** This will only allow you intercept expansion events triggered by the user clicking on the expand button [+]. There are several keyboard shortcuts will you need to implement support for yourself.

HTH,

Comment: Descending from TreeView seems like overkill. You could probably do this much more easily with an attached behavior.

Comment: @JoeWhite: Absolutely you can do this with an attached behaviour however thought that too advanced of a topic to cover in this answer.